# Issues with building Windows app with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I tried executing `flutter build windows` but got these errors:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1116,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of  will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are \\core_implementations.cc, \\standard_codec.cc, \\flutter_engine.cc, \\flutter_view_controller.cc. [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "CL.exe". System.ArgumentException: The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share. [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.LongPathHelper.Normalize(String path, UInt32 maxPathLength, Boolean checkInvalidCharacters, Boolean expandShortPaths) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\5338ScoutingApp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileUtilities.NormalizePath(String path) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]      
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker.FormatRootingMarker(ITaskItem[] sources, ITaskItem[] outputs) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.ComputeOutOfDateSources() [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_app.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1116,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of  will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are \\core_implementations.cc, \\standard_codec.cc, \\plugin_registrar.cc. [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]       
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "CL.exe". System.ArgumentException: The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share. [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.LongPathHelper.Normalize(String path, UInt32 maxPathLength, Boolean checkInvalidCharacters, Boolean expandShortPaths) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileUtilities.NormalizePath(String path) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]   
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker.FormatRootingMarker(ITaskItem[] sources, ITaskItem[] outputs) [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.ComputeOutOfDateSources() [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(734,5): error MSB6001:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\pneum\Scouting App\Sapp\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_wrapper_plugin.vcxproj]"
```

I tried flutter clean and pub get, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.